# Using pivotlonger on multiple variables of horse racing dataframe in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, tidyr

Hi and Thanks in advance for any assistance the group can give.

I have a dataset which gives the performance ratings for 7 race horses
over their last 3 races. The performance ratings are DaH1, DaH2 and DaH3 where
DaH1 is the performance rating for the last race etc.
I also have data for race distances over which the races were ran, where the distances are
Dist1, Dist2 and Dist3 and they correspond to the performance ratings. ie. Horse 2 has a 
performance rating of 124 for DaH1, with a race distance, Dist1, of 12.

The dataset is:

```
horse_data <- tibble(
  DaH1=c(0, 124, 121, 123, 0, NA, 110),
  DaH2=c(124, 117, 125, 120, 125, 0, NA),
  DaH3=c(121, 119, 123, 119, NA, 0, 123),
  Dist1 =c(10,12,10.3,11,11.5,14,10),
  Dist2 =c(10,10.1,12,8,9.5,10.25,8.75),
  Dist3 =c(11.5,12.5,9.8,10,10,15,10),
  horse =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
)
```

I am trying to use pivot_longer to convert the data to a better dataset for performing
calculations depending upon race distances.
So far I used this code:

```
tidyData <- horse_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    values_to="Rating", 
    cols=c(DaH1, DaH2, DaH3), 
    names_prefix="DaH", 
    names_to="RaceIdx"
  )
```

To achieve:

```
> tidyData
# A tibble: 21 x 6
   Dist1 Dist2 Dist3 horse RaceIdx Rating
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1  10    10    11.5     1 1            0
 2  10    10    11.5     1 2          124
 3  10    10    11.5     1 3          121
 4  12    10.1  12.5     2 1          124
 5  12    10.1  12.5     2 2          117
 6  12    10.1  12.5     2 3          119
 7  10.3  12     9.8     3 1          121
 8  10.3  12     9.8     3 2          125
 9  10.3  12     9.8     3 3          123
10  11     8    10       4 1          123
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Where RaceIdx is the race number.
This has achieved the desired result for 'Rating' column but I need to be able to convert
Dist1, Dist2 and Dist3 in to a separate column 'Distance' that matches up each horses 
corresponding DaH rating with Dist.
To illustrate, I am trying to end up with a dataset as follows:

```
      Distance horse RaceIdx Rating
      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1      10       1 1            0
 2      10       1 2          124
 3      11       1 3          121
 4      12       2 1          124
 5      10.1     2 2          117
 6      12.5     2 3          119
 7      10.3     3 1          121
 8      12       3 2          125
 9      9.8      3 3          123
10      11       4 1          123
# ... with 11 more rows
```

I need to filter the Ratings by Distance.
Then I hope to be able to produce average ratings for each horse ratings where the
race Distance is between 10 and 11.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the `names_sep` with a regex lookaround

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
horse_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(horse), names_to = c('.value', 'RaceIdx'), 
        names_sep="(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
  rename(Distance = Dist, Rating = DaH)
# A tibble: 21 x 4
#   horse RaceIdx Rating Distance
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1 1            0     10  
# 2     1 2          124     10  
# 3     1 3          121     11.5
# 4     2 1          124     12  
# 5     2 2          117     10.1
# 6     2 3          119     12.5
# 7     3 1          121     10.3
# 8     3 2          125     12  
# 9     3 3          123      9.8
#10     4 1          123     11  
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Hi. I ran this code. Thanks.  All good except the final section of the code:          rename(Distance = Dist, Rating = DaH)             results in the error: Error in rename(., Distance = Dist, Rating = DaH) : 
  unused arguments (Distance = Dist, Rating = DaH)           Any idea why this may be?

Comment: @Bookie Are you using the `dplyr::rename` and what is your `dplyr` version.  I used 1.0.0